# How to record Jmeter Script - Browser Proxy Settings window is disabled and not allowing blazemeter chrome extention

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, proxy

In our organisation, Browser Proxy Settings (connections) window is disabled and not allowing blazemeter chrome extention. Please help me, to record the script with jmeter?

Answer (score 1):

Every browser comes with [Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and each implementation of the developer tools allows inspecting network traffic (HTTP request and responses)

Theoretically it should be sufficient for building the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers manually by replicating all the parameters and [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

If the number of requests is large and you don't have enough time you can [export captured network traffic in form of HAR file](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204410413-Generating-a-HAR-file-for-troubleshooting) and once done use [online converter of .HAR, .PCAP, Selenium, .etc scripts into JMeter JMX files](https://converter.blazemeter.com/)